# Filter Categories from list of Products in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So I'm working on this Django e-commerce website where I'm supposed to filter the products on my page based on three separate categories. Since there were only three fixed categories, I decided to create a dictionary in my model class for Products and thought there would be a way to filter products later on in my templates accordingly using a {%For%} loop.

It's not working as I expected tho and I'm getting errors, probably because I'm not that familiar with Django and don't know how to get my way around it. Would greatly appreciate the help! (I've attached some screenshots for context)

[MODELS.products screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsVqu.png)

[working implementation of for loop that directly shows all products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqU5n.png)

[Views.catalogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIovA.png)

Comment: To better assist, I'd recommend that you upload the portion of the `html` containing the `loop`, `urls.py` and the `views.py` file in code, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is that you add an `anchor tag` inside of the `for loop` that will have the `category name` which you can then pass as a `keyword` to a defined `url` for categories.

For example:

In the `html`...

```
{% for product in products %}
     ...
     # Adding this anchor tag to your existing code within the loop that will display each product's category.
     # Also you can now send this category name to a specific view to filter the products
     
     <a href="{% url 'category' product.category %}">{{ product.category|title }}</a>
     # Notice that I have passed product.category as a keyword in {% url 'category' product.category %} 
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

Now within your `urls.py` file, just create a url to handle categories passed as keywords.

```
from .views import category_view  # Importing the new view

urlpatterns = [
     ...    
     path('category/<str:category>/', category_view, name='category'),
     ...
]
```

From the `views.py` file.

```
def category_view(request, category): # Accepting the category passed here
     # You can have any other operations in here if necessary

     products = Product.objects.filter(category__iexact=category)

     context = {
          ...
          'products': products,
          ...
     }
     return render(request, 'products.html', context)
```

That's the basic concept of what would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Class Based Views for the solutions. Basically you want to show the list of the products by category right. So the solution is as follows.

on views.py the view class is like this:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Product

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'products'
    template_name = 'your-template-path'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset()
        category = self.request.GET.get('category', None)
        if category:
            return queryset.filter(category=category)
        return queryset
```

Now send the category values on your URL parameter using category keyword. I am not using any authentication system. Please implement it on your own

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to pass these values in Html, using a for loop? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Means the way you have written in that way?

Comment: yeah, {% for product in products %}

Comment: what should I write so that I can filter out one of the categories, for instance 'toys', form the products and list them on my catalogue page?

Comment: This is incorrect since you mentioned sending the category as a `kwarg` over the `url`. Where you have `category = self.request.GET.get('category', None)` should be corrected to `category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)`.

Comment: Sorry I meant URL parameter not kwarg